# PHP multiple object function calls

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

This maybe a silly question.

I am trying to understand how these series of object calls are made. Example in Laravel eloquent method
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

```
$affectedRows = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->update(array('status' => 2));
```

I am trying to create a custom framework, and i like the idea of the Laravel framework. 
Can someone please tell me what it is and how to achieve this.

Comment: see Fluent_interface http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: Fluent interface, thats one thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is called method chaining and is done by returning a reference to the class( $this ), or another class object from those functions. Then you can call a method on the returned object.

Here is a simple example.

```
class foo{
     protected $_bar;

     public function bar($value){
          $this->_bar = $value;
          return $this;
    }


   public function out(){
        echo $this->_bar;
   }
}

$a = new foo();
$a->bar('hello')->out();
```

output:

```
'hello'
```

Just to explain a bit more, the above code `$a->bar('hello')->out();` is roughly equivalent to doing this:

```
 $a = new foo();
 $b = $a->bar('hello');  //$a and $b are the same instance of the object
 $b->out();
```

Now because `bar()` returns `$this` we could assign it to `$b` like above and then call `out()`.  But `$a` and `$b` both reference the same instance of the `foo` object, because we returned `$this` from `bar()`.  So there is no need for this extra "spurious" variable as we can just reference the return object directly for the next call.  This works with any object that is returned from a method (not just $this), but obviously then the next call in the chain is against the returned object.